# Setting selection by text in CComboBox (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a CComboBox of type `DropList` (i.e. it's not editable). What's the easiest way to set the current selection by string?

I know I can use `SetCurSel()` to set it by index, but I want the function to search through the list-items by string and set it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about CComboBox::SelectString ?

"Searches for a string in the list box of a combo box, and if the string is found, selects the string in the list box and copies it to the edit control."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30ft9e54(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8):

You can call [FindStringExact()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzf0ht83.aspx) to obtain the index of the string you want to select, then pass that index to [SetCurSel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at7s2662.aspx):

```
yourComboBox.SetCurSel(yourComboBox.FindStringExact(0, yourString));
```

Note that is the string is not found in the combobox, `-1` will be passed to `SetCurSel()`, which will result in any previous selection being cleared. You may want to perform an explicit test if that behavior does not suit you.

*Note that [Max's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32867469/464709) should be preferred for new developments. However, `SelectString()` is only supported from Windows Server 2003 onwards, so you may not be able to leverage it, depending on the platforms you want to support.*

Comment: you can also use SelectString to directly select it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30ft9e54.aspx

Comment: Cool, new in Windows Server 2003 (it's been a long time since I've had to use MFC, and it shows). I'll update my answer accordingly and leave it around in case someone has to support XP and earlier.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - yours, in fact, *IS* a correct answer. The `CComboBox::SelectString()` will select any string if it starts with `yourString`; that's why you should use FindStringExact(). Of course, if that kind of differences matter to you :)