# ComboBox - OnCtlColor : How to color the whole list rect

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to color the `rect` of the list of my derived ComboBox class. In the `OnCtlColor`, I'm drawing a rect with `FillSolidRect`, but when I put my mouse over the list, It loses all the text (only the one selected stays). Here's my code :

```
HBRUSH CColoredComboBox::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CComboBox::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_LISTBOX || nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_EDIT || nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_MSGBOX)
    {
        CRect rect;
        pDC->GetClipBox(&rect);
        // fill the rectangular area with the color
        pDC->FillSolidRect(&rect, RGB(255, 0, 255));
        hbr = m_brBkgnd;
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0, 255, 0));
        pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255, 0, 255));
    }

    return hbr;
}
```

I think I need to `DrawText` the text back, someone knows how ?

I've seen some people were subclassing `CEdit` and `CListCtrl`, should I try that ?

Thx :)

Comment: `OnCtlColor()` is not meant for drawing. You are only allowed to modify device context state, e. g. `CDC::SetBkColor`, `CDC::SetTextColor` and return a brush.

Answer (score 1):

I added this in the OnCtlColor function after the `SetBkColor`

```
        int numItems = GetCount();
        char text[1024];
        int height = GetItemHeight(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) 
        {
            GetLBText(i, text);
            CRect pos(rect.left + 2, rect.top + (height * i), rect.right, rect.bottom);
            DrawText(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), text, -1, &pos, DT_SINGLELINE);
        }
```

This is how I was able to solve my problem ! :)

Comment: The `new CRect` is pointless here, you're leaking memory. And i'ts unclear where the code snippet you posted should be.

Comment: This answer makes no sense, even after the edit. How do you obtain `rect`? How do you find highlighted items?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani The `rect` is obtained by your pDC `CRect rect;
        pDC->GetClipBox(&rect);` and for the selected item, you can check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867099/setting-selection-by-text-in-ccombobox-mfc

Comment: `GetClipBox` returns the wrong rectangle. It looks like you are attempting to repaint the listbox portion of the combobox in response to `WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT` message. I don't see how this could work.